# Icon Name is not showing properly

Tags: ios, icons, application-name

I am facing odd issue.My proj should run in iphone 3gs, 4 and 5. when I am installing my application to device, application name showing different way. I mean lets say my application name is XYZ Business, then it is showing 'XYZ...ess' in 3gs and 'XYZ Bus...' in 4 and 5. I am not able to understand why it is showing like this.please help me. thanking you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there is no restriction on number of characters in App Name. But if app name has more then 12 characters then it will truncate.

But

It's very difficult to find, how long iPhone and iPad App name could be without shrinking ?

Apple(iOS) shrinks the App name based on total width of the given name.

For example, width of char "i" is less than char "W".
So if App name contains thin characters like "i", App name could have longer without shrink and if App name contains thick characters like "W", App name could have smaller without shrink.

FYI! iPad is having wider space than iPhone, so iPad App name could have more characters than iPhone.

Comment: Nice explanation. But here question is how this is different with version of OS and devices?

Comment: how to fix this issue ?